# Spring post rest cant parse objects in object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make a post call to my spring boot backend so i can store some items. The object that i want to store has other objects in it, this is the current design of the database. [image]

Now i want to do a post call to create a partsused object in the database. I send this Json object to spring boot, but get the error that amount_type_id cannot be null. So i think it cant parse the object, can anybody see what is wrong with my class/json object because i cant find the problem

```
{
    "amount":"2",
    "specification":"test",
    "partType":{
        "idPartType":4,
        "type":"leveringen"},
    "amountType":{
        "idAmountType":5,
        "type":"m3"},
    "project":{
        "idProject":4,
        "description":"test",
        "isFinished":false,
        "startDate":"2019-12-11",
        "finishDate":null,
        "name":"test2"
    }
}
```

My partsused class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonSerialize
private Long idPartsUsed;
private int amount;
private String specification;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "part_type_id", referencedColumnName = "idPartType")
private PartType partType;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "amount_type_id", referencedColumnName = "idAmountType")
private AmountType amountType;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "idProject")
private Project project;
```

my amounttype class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonSerialize
private Long idAmountType;
private String type;
```

The error message

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": {
            "cause": null,
            "message": "Column 'amount_type_id' cannot be null"
        },
        "message": "could not execute statement"
    },
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

Comment: please post more information like the error you are getting, the API code etc etc

Comment: @SurajGautam i have added the error message for you, and i just get back a basic 400 code

Comment: Hi, why are you auto-incrementing primary key for idAmountType in AmountType class and sending it in json?

Comment: @SurajGautam i thought i needed to specify the id for the post call otherwise it would create a new AmountType in the database which i dont want, i want it to link to the excisting AmountType

Comment: In your request, "amount":"2", but amount datatype is int in partsused class, can you try with "amount":2, in the request ?

Comment: @SB as an int i still get the same problem that amount_type_id cannot be null, so it doesnt parse that object for some reason

Comment: You are manually setting your generatedId. That's the problem I guess.

Comment: @SurajGautam when i remove the id's from the objects it still gives the same error, can it maybe be something about my joins?

Comment: Try with referencedColumnName="id_amount_type".

Comment: @SB then it is unable to find column id_amount_type in table amounttype

Comment: Even after marking @Id with @Column(name="id_amount_type") in AmountType ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child entity, you are generating id by doing `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in `AmountType`, `PartType`, `Project` classes. But, you are also sending the value of id from JSON itself. This is where the problem is.

So, firstly, remove the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` code from the child entities.

Add secondly, add `CascadeType.ALL` to your mapping.

I tried it in my machine and it worked.

The code that I tried is given below.

**AmountType.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="amount_type")
public class AmountType {
@Id
@JsonSerialize
private Long idAmountType;
private String type;
}
```

**PartType.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="part_type")
public class PartType {
@Id
@JsonSerialize
private Long idPartType;
private String type;

}
```

**Project.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

@Id
private Long idProject;
private String description;
private boolean isFinished;
private String startDate;
private String finishDate;
private String name;
}
```

**PartsUsed.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parts_used")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PartsUsed {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonSerialize
private Long idPartsUsed;
private int amount;
private String specification;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "part_type_id", referencedColumnName = "idPartType")
private PartType partType;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "amount_type_id", referencedColumnName = "idAmountType")
private AmountType amountType;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "idProject")
private Project project;


}
```

This is the controller that receives POST request to create parts.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody PartsUsed partsUsed) {
        jpaRepositoryTest.save(partsUsed);
        return "test";
    }
```

This is how I sent the request using your payload.
[image]

This is how the data is inserted in table. I used h2 databse.

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

I think that when spring creates its own end points with the @RepositoryRestResource it functions differently than when you create your own endpoint with an @RestController + @PostMapping. When i used my own rest controller it got the id's of the amount type and other objects as well.

This is my Repository, i dont know if there is anything wrong with the way i set it up but now it works

```
@Repository("PartsUsedRepository")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "results", path = "partsused")
public interface PartsUsedRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PartsUsed, Long> {
}
```